# Text above horizontal aligned tables are not aligning

Tags: formatting

I have a table that covers horizontally like 1/3 of the page. I want another table next to it and thats working fine by using:

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{ c | c | c }
    numbers&text&something\\
    1&test&test\\
    2&hello&what\\
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ c | c | c }
    test&test\\
    1&testing\\
    1&testingagain\\
\end{tabular}
```

But when I add text to both of the tables to be shown above the tables, it doesnt work:

```
\textbf{somerandombold}\\
\begin{tabular}[t]{ c | c | c }
    numbers&text&something\\
    1&test&test\\
    2&hello&what\\
\end{tabular}
\textbf{somemorerandombold}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ c | c | c }
    test&test\\
    1&testing\\
    1&testingagain\\
\end{tabular}
```

The bolded text of the second table just starts horizontally in the middle of the first table and the table itself will go to a whole new line under the first table.

When I remove the linebreak between the bolded text and the second table, it will go next to eachother which I dont want.

I want it like this:

```
bolded text                         bolded text
numbers|text|something              test|test
```

etc...

I was thinking about putting the bolded text together on one line and then a line break and then the 2 tables but how would I even line that up the right way then?

But I cant figure out how to get this desired output. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should do more or less what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{eqparbox}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\noindent%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}X|X@{}|}
  \textbf{somerandombold} & \textbf{somemorerandombold} \\
  \eqmakebox[T1]{ \begin{tabular}[t]{ c | c | c|}
      numbers & text & something \\
      1 & test & test \\
      2 & hello & what
    \end{tabular}} &
  \eqmakebox[T2]{\begin{tabular}[t]{ c | c | c }
      test & test \\
      1 & testing \\
      1 & testingagain
    \end{tabular}} \\
  \addlinespace[3ex]
  \parbox[t]{\eqboxwidth{T1}}{ Random text1 Random text1 Random text1 \\
    Ending random text1\\}
                                             &
  \parbox[t]{\eqboxwidth{T2}}{Random text2 \\
    Ending random text2\\}
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I might have forgotten something but I have an error at your first example at the \end{tabularx} `Paragraph ended before \begin was complete`

Comment: @Loko: It my fault: I mistyped `\begin{tabularx}` (forgot the closing brace).

Comment: Now Im getting a lot of errors: `environment tabular undefined` `missing number treated as zero` `illegal unit of measure` `misplaced alignment tab` all at the first 2 lines

Comment: I suppose you mean ‘tabular`x`’ undefined. You have  to load it with `\usepackage`, of course.

Comment: Is there a way to add a third row underneath it with lines of multiple lines next to eachother?

Comment: @Loko: I don't understand very well what you want. Adding a paragraph under each table, so the paragraphs are top-aligned, even if the tables do not have the same height?

Comment: Sorry I dont understand the code 100% yet. Lets say I have another part I want horizontally aligned: both of the parts have 3 lines of random text. How can I get them under the table horizontally aligned ?

Comment: Do you want  these lines to have the same width as the tables, or to have ‘column’ width? And do you use the solution with `tabularx` or with `minipage`s?

Comment: I want them to align with the tables vertically yes. And I use tabularx

Comment: Could you post a full compilable code? Will the table have the same height in real life?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62914/discussion-between-loko-and-bernard).

Comment: thank you for the edit by the way. It works but my whole page has borders around it now. Actually every page hard borders around the content now.

Comment: Sorry for this problem. It's simple: remove the `[showframe]` option of `geometry` – it's in the code just to check there's no overflow in the margin. Naively I thought everyone was aware of this option, so I didn't even mention it.

Comment: Thanks so much for helping me through this. Everything works now.